# Link problem between projects in same solution (Exe depends on Lib)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have one solution with several projects. Say `ProjectA` is the one that will produce the exe file, and `ProjectB` simply produces a `.lib` file. I have checked that `ProjectA` depends on `ProjectB`, so that `ProjectB` will always compile before `ProjectA`.

When I compile `ProjectB` everything goes fine. But if I compile `ProjectA` I get linking errors saying that some method of B does not exist. I have checked, and it does exist.

¿What is going on?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is very likely that the method actually does not exist. Maybe you missed a `const` or something? Please post the code that causes the error (the function and the referencing code) as well as the exact linker error message.

Comment: This is not enough (read my comment again). Also, please do not post the code as comment, but rather edit you own question to add new information.

Comment: Are the two projects coded in C++? If you use C in one project and C++ in another you have to declare functions with `extern "C"`. [more info here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Project Properties, Linker, General: Set "Link Library Dependencies" to Yes.

Comment: Ok, that worked, but I had to add /FORCE:MULTIPLE to additional options in the linker command line, because it was giving me other linking errors with LIBCMTD.lib

Comment: @Sara: You should make both projects use the same runtime, or you may get funny errors. "Properties, C/C++, Code Generation, Runtime Library"

Comment: @Sara: As said... make both projects use the same runtime

Comment: When I added the /FORCE:MULTIPLE it gave me a lot of warnings concerning LIBCMT...should I be worried?

Comment: You shouldn't use /FORCE:MULTIPLE if you can avoid it. LIBC conflicts can cause strange problems.

Comment: Cool.  I didn't know you could have the libraries link this way.  I've always explicitly told the linker to link the library in by name.  It seemed a bit silly to have to do that.  This way makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found there were several things I needed to check to fix the vexing link error:

> "link.exe" exited with code 1104.

1. As per @Eric's answer, on the top level (Project A) : `Project -> Linker -> General -> Link Library Dependencies : Yes`

[image: Link Library Dependencies]

2. Select the parent / top level project, and in the Project Properties prop list, click `Project Depdendencies` and ensure `Project A` references `Project B`

[image: Project Dependencies]

3. Somewhat counter intuitively, on `ProjectA` ensure that you don't have an additional linker library dependency on `ProjectB.lib`. This seems to encourage to look VS to look for **another** library called `ProjectB.lib`, elsewhere.

[image]

- You do not need to add the output directory of ProjectB to ProjectA's additional Link directories (default is `$(SolutionDir)$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\`).